# ios and android payments with paypal App store Guidelines

Tags: android, ios, paypal, google-play

I'm a part of a team developing a system that will allow students to send questions using an app to private tutors. Tutors see the question, answer it and get paid.
Each students starts with some free questions and after that he is required to either buy questions or earn questions via coupon or referral program.

We have a few questions according to that after these reading Apple guidelines:

> 11. Purchasing and currencies
>
> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
> rejected

So i can't be sure if we can integrate PayPal, referral or coupons and stay in the app store and google play

any one know and can give a certificate answer?
or know where we can get any certificate answer?
without knowing it for sure we might drop the project, there is nothing worse then work only to discover later on that we got ban from the stores

Thank you for any help you can supply

Answer (score 0):

11.2 sums it up for iOS, you must use In-App Purchase for purchase from within the app. You may not direct or link the user to an outside payment option.

It is possible to use payments completely outside the app in a similar manner to Amazon Books but there can to be a link or reference to that service. Take a good hard look at Amazon Kindle app.